Is it possible to change current position marker icon in Mapbox Navigation SDK Kotlin?
I'm using Mapbox Navigation SDK Kotlin (in flutter). I'm able to change the destination icon with this code Link to Doc
this@TurnByTurn.binding.navigationView.customizeViewStyles {
                        this.destinationMarkerAnnotationOptions=
                        PointAnnotationOptions().apply {
                            withIconImage(
                                ContextCompat.getDrawable(
                                    activity,
                                    R.drawable.ic_launcher
                                )!!.toBitmap()
                            )
                        }
                    }

But I couldn't find a way to change the current position icon in the map. Is it possible?
